# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space MultipartRequest

Tags: java, out-of-memory, multipartform-data, heap-memory

I have a problem with a MultipartRequest, when I try to upload file. 
The error is: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
I think that the error is in the while cicle, but I don't know what's wrong.
Thanks.

This is my code:

```
InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];

while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}

buffer.flush();

byte[] out = buffer.toByteArray();
```

> 10-Jun-2015 15:39:45.146 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-307]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [tw] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.ServiceInterceptorFactory$1] (value
>   [com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.ServiceInterceptorFactory$1@5901535e]) and
>   a value of type [java.util.HashSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove
>   it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be
>   renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak. 10-Jun-2015
>   15:39:45.146 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-307]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [tw] created a ThreadLocal with key of type
>   [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value
>   [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@1e3025db]) and a value of
>   type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator[]] (value
>   [[Lcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator;@d9e64e7]) but failed to
>   remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to
>   be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
>   10-Jun-2015 15:39:57.464 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-307]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with
>   name [/tw] is completed NOME PART: 1031.zip 10-Jun-2015 15:40:45.772
>   SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-308] null.null caught throwable 
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: please post the stack trace.

Comment: Posted in my question

Comment: Looks like you are creating thread locals and not removing them after use.
I think the code that you have posted is not relevant here. Please post the code where you are using the thread locals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your heap space. If you are using eclipse you can check [this link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) and it will show you how to increase the heap size (heap memory is the "place" where all your objects are stored)